# jquery equivalent replaceWith in dojo

Tags: javascript, jquery, dojo

I just started using dojo and for some strange reason the `place` method for swapping dom nodes does not seem to work as expected

I tried this in dojo but did not work

```
dojo.place(dojo.query('#logCount'), dojo.query('.pagebanner'), 'after')
```

Given that I have a background in jquery I decided to give it a try using jquery.

```
$('#logCount').replaceWith($('.pagebanner'));
```

The jquery worked as expected. Wondering why the dojo version is not working given that they are kind of doing the same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're very close, but `dojo.query` is returning arrays, and what you want is these specific domNodes to get moved. So this assumes there's only one of each:

```
dojo.place(dojo.query("#logCount")[0], dojo.query('.pagebanner')[0], 'replace')
```